# Hide connection line in TimeSeries plot in JFreeChart

Tags: time-series, jfreechart

In time series, there a time gap of certain duration. When chart is plotted the gap is replaced by a straight line.

Using `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` can control whether the item or line is visible using the following calls:

```
renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(series, false);
renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(series, false);
```

but it affects the whole series.

How can i avoid this straight line for the time gap in time series plot?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117479).

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in `getItemLineVisible(int, int)` in the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` class - it is the value returned by this method that determines whether or not a line segment is drawn between the current item and the previous item.  The default implementation checks the `linesVisible` flag and the flags at the series level:

```
280    public boolean getItemLineVisible(int series, int item) {
281        Boolean flag = this.linesVisible;
282        if (flag == null) {
283            flag = getSeriesLinesVisible(series);
284        }
285        if (flag != null) {
286            return flag.booleanValue();
287        }
288        else {
289            return this.baseLinesVisible;
290        }
291    }
```

However, you can override this method and return a different boolean result for any item.